# New Jenkins rendering of Build Parameter much less compact

Tags: css, jenkins, html-rendering

Hi I've recently upgraded my version of Jenkins from version: **2.263.4** to **2.346.3**.
I've noticed the Build Parameters for my job, are noticeably less compact than the previous version.

To compare, old Pipeline build parameters:

[image]

New Pipeline build parameters:

[image]

For the new String parameter **name**, **description** and **value** are all rendered on top of each other. Whereas before the **value** was directly across from the **name**, and the **description** was below the **value** in a smaller font.

To me the new rendering layout is far less clean, and is also more confusing when you have builds with a lot of parameters.

Is there any way to revert back to the old style with the new version of Jenkins?

Comment: Not really. You could try some custom css, but the better course of action is the express the concern to the Jenkins Core Community. You will find many similar remarks on [Jenkins glitter ux](https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/ux-sig), [Jenkins community](https://community.jenkins.io/latest) and [Jenkins users](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users) and [dev](https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-sec). Reach out to the [UX-SIG](https://www.jenkins.io/sigs/ux/); see [see minutes](https://community.jenkins.io/t/user-experience-sig-november-9-2022/4544)

Comment: See [Tampa's many posts](https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/ux-sig?at=632e61b46837563d1ceb6968) and responses (might have some css there) and [Ionnasis complaint](https://community.jenkins.io/t/new-ui-form-spacing-and-poor-usability/3885)